# I have tried to set default value in v-bind:max with a variable

Tags: vue.js

Hi I have a date input which I want to add a max attribute because I want to allow that the user can pick the date under that date so I have my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fecha de Recaudación</label>
    <input type="date"
       class="form-control" 
       id="exampleInputEmail1"
       v-bind:max="datePickerOptions"
       v-model="form.collection_date" 
       placeholder="Ingresa la fecha de la recaudación" 
       required>
</div>
```

My VueJs code:

```
export default {
    created() {
        this.getBranchOfficeList();
        this.getDate();
    },
    methods: {
        getDate() {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setDate(d.getDate()-5);
            const ye = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(d);
            const mo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'numeric' }).format(d);
            const da = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: 'numeric' }).format(d);

            if(ye < 10) {
                var new_year = '0' + ye;
            } else {
                var new_year = ye;
            }
            if(mo < 10) {
                var new_month = '0' + mo;
            } else {
                var new_month = mo;
            }
            if(da < 10) {
                var new_day = '0' + da;
            } else {
                var new_day = da;
            }
            this.date_picker = new_year +'-'+ new_month + '-' + new_day;
        }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            datePickerOptions: this.date_picker
        }
    },
    computed: {
        isDisabled() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

How you can see datePickerOptions has a value which it comes from this.date_picker which it comes from the method getDate() but It does not work why?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, your mechanism should work, as demontrated in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/jangnoe/Le3fdtab/3/, so it there might be something off with datePickerOptions. Maybe you could print the value of datePickerOptions below the input, something like ' <pre>{{datePickerOptions}}</pre>' to see what is going on with that value.

Comment: @JoshuaAngnoe you are setting the date manually, it worked to me but the thing is when I try to set this one with the function getDate()

Comment: Yes I understand that was your goal. You should check if the date calculated by your getDate function has the right format, "YYYY-MM-DD", it should have a total length of 12. When troubleshooting this sort of problem you try to pinpoint where you went wrong, verifying if the mechanism (like we did with the example) is a good first step. Next step is to verify if our inputs are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having it as a method you can use a computed property. Also remove the method getDate() since the name is a reserved function name

```
 datan() {
        return {
            date_picker: null,
            form: {        // I have defined the form object here since you are using it in the v-model
               .....
            }
        }
    },
computed: {
    isDisabled() {
            return true;
        },
    computeMaxDate() {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setDate(d.getDate()-5);
            const ye = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(d);
            const mo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'numeric' }).format(d);
            const da = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: 'numeric' }).format(d);

            if(ye < 10) {
                var new_year = '0' + ye;
            } else {
                var new_year = ye;
            }
            if(mo < 10) {
                var new_month = '0' + mo;
            } else {
                var new_month = mo;
            }
            if(da < 10) {
                var new_day = '0' + da;
            } else {
                var new_day = da;
            }
            this.date_picker = new_year +'-'+ new_month + '-' + new_day;
            return this.date_picker;
        }
}
```

and the modified template block is

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fecha de Recaudación</label>
    <input type="date"
       class="form-control" 
       id="exampleInputEmail1"
       :max="computeMaxDate"
       v-model="form.collection_date" 
       placeholder="Ingresa la fecha de la recaudación" 
       required>
</div>
```

Here in the computed property I have just copy pasted your logic...so you need to make sure that the value thats getting stored in the 'date_picker' is of the below format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD // eg: 2021-01-19
```

if its not of the above format then you need to debug and have it fixed